# text-align для inline-block

Tags: html, css

Hужно задать элементу `h1` `text-align: center;`

`h1` имеет свойство `display: inline-block;`

```css
h1 {
display: inline-block;
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А может просто `float`?

```css
h1 { float: right; }
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

Для `inline` блока это так не работает.

- Либо оберните его во внешний блок и уже родителю задавайте `text-align`
- Либо для него задайте `width`
- Либо установите значение `display: block;`

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red
}

.wrapper {
text-align: center;

background-color: lightYellow
}

.inlineWidth {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightBlue;
}


.block {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightGreen;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="inline">inline-block</h1>

<div class="wrapper"><h1 class="inline">inline-block</h1></div>

<h1 class="inlineWidth">inline-block and width</h1>

<h1 class="block">block</h1>
```